# How to auto switch input method by app

Tags: macos

My mac has several input methods (English, Chinese)

When I open terminal / iterm2 , I want the input method to switch to `English`  automatically.

When I open skype or chat messenger , I want the input method to switch to `Chinese` automatically.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem and solve it by the following approach.

> 1. choose System Preferences
> 2. select the Keyboard option
> 3. Select the Input Sources tab, and then check the box next to Automatically switch to a document’s input source option

Source: https://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/53194/os-x-switch-language-input-sources-automatically/

Answer (score 1):

> You can try going to system prefs/language & text/input sources and checking the box for "allow a different one for each document," but this may not do what you want.

Source: ["Automatic Language Input Change"](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2622336) on the Apple Support community

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [GhostSKB](https://github.com/dingmingxin/GhostSKB)

You guys really need to try it yourself, then come back to vote or de-vote this answer

Comment: This github repo does not exist anymore. Link returns 404.